How can I tell what function runs when you paste from the right-click menu?
I have made a serious error and pasting from the right-click menu does not behave as C-y does. I could bisect my config files and find the source of the error, but I would rather figure out what function is being run when I right-click and paste. How can I work this out? The right-click menu gives no information beyond just "paste".

C-h k  followed by a right-click at that location should tell you. In my case, it says: <mouse-3> (translated from <down-mouse-3> <mouse-3>) at that spot runs the command mouse-save-then-kill (found in global-map), which is an interactive native-comp-function in ‘mouse.el’.

@NickD Correct. Post as an answer.

I can do better than that: the question is a duplicate and it already has a (very good) answer.
